# Understanding virtual / override

Tags: c#, inheritance

I thought I knew the overall idea of the keywords, but trying to get my head on how it applies to the following code. I get the same values whether I use override/virtual or not (on method GetTotal).

What's the deal? Does override/virtual even apply to this, since they don't seem to be doing anything.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
  class ChaseAccount : BankAccount
  {
    public override int GetTotal()
    {
      return Total * 1000;
    }
  }


  class BankAccount
  {
    public int Total { get; set; }
    public virtual int GetTotal()
    {
      return Total * 100;
    }

    public BankAccount Deposit(int n)
    {
      this.Total += n;
      return this;
    }
  }

  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      // BankAccount
      BankAccount ba = new BankAccount();
      ba.Deposit(1000);
      Console.WriteLine(ba.GetTotal());


      Console.WriteLine("\n\n");

      // Chase
      ChaseAccount ca = new ChaseAccount();
      ca.Deposit(1000);
      Console.WriteLine(ca.GetTotal());


      Console.ReadLine();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Downvote - Readup on inheritance. Your override code does the same as your virtual code in your base class. Of course you will get the same result. Virtual is supposed to give you a (possible) base implementation, and override should extend or override that.

Comment: I modified my question. Thanks everyone for kindly telling me to update my post.

Comment: Do you still see the behavior with that code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to stem from a lack of understanding regarding the keywords... `override` is used to modify a method in a subclass which is marked `virtual` in the class' parent. `virtual` means that no matter how an instance is cast, the method from the most derived subclass of the object is called (as long as the subclass provides a version of the method marked `override`).

In your example above `virtual` never does anything because you have a BankAccount stored as a BankAccount and a ChaseAccount stored as a ChaseAccount. If the ChaseAccount was cast to a BankAccount, though, then when you called `GetTotal()` it would call BankAccount's `GetTotal()` completely naive to the fact that the BankAccount is actually a ChaseAccount - *unless* the method was marked `virtual` to force a call to ChaseAccount's version of `GetTotal()` (assuming it was marked `override`) instead.

[I've made an illustration at Ideone](http://ideone.com/oYNGAi)

Comment: Sorry my question wasn't clear. Thanks for your clear explanation.

Comment: @SaltProgrammer - not a problem! Everyone's new to every concept at least once... Doesn't make sense to make a big stink over it, IMO.

Comment: @SaltProgrammer added an illustrative example.